# Relationships between tables in Sentry shema

Tags: laravel, cartalyst-sentry

Why in Sentry 2 database schema, relationships between tables don't exist? For example between `users` and `users_groups` table. Do I have to manually set that?

Answer (score 0):

Sentry will create the needed tables for you so you do not nee to make any other changes.

There are no foreign keys if this is what you asking. Foreign keys are just way to help guarantee the data integrity and are not required.